# Inner Function Can Not Be Executed/Invoked

Tags: python, python-2.7

im a newbie in Python, appreciate your help in advance.
I am using Python v2.x on Windows 7 os.

The goal of my program is talking to robot (via Serial) and let the robot move some dist. Please see code in below.

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial( )
ser.port = 'COM4'
ser = serial.Serial('COM4', 9600, timeout = 0.05)
print ser

def tryIt():
    def runRobot():
        ser.write('testmode on \n')
        ser.write('setmotor lwheeldist 200 speed 100 rwheeldist 200 speed 100 \n')

tryIt()
ser.close()
```

The thing I feel wired is, 'tryIt' function could be called, but the inner function 'runRobot' cannot be invoked. Serial communication has no problem. No error report pops out...and I am confusing...Any advice please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have just defined `runRobot()` within `tryIt()` but you are not making a call to that function. Update `tryIt()` as mentioned below and it will work.

```
def tryIt():
    def runRobot():
        ser.write('testmode on \n')
        ser.write('setmotor lwheeldist 200 speed 100 rwheeldist 200 speed 100 \n')
    runRobot()
```

Comment: believe me, i tried. but system does not allow me to accept it until 10 minutes later...

Comment: It is ok. No problem.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the tryit method you need to call runrobot.

Alternatively why have a nested definitions?